# Possible to induce AC power on a DC conductor using Magnetic Induction?

Tags: ac, dc, generator

Ok, my science terminology is not good, so just bear with me. I'm not a scientist, or in school for this, I'm just trying to learn independently.

I'm trying to make a certain kind of electrical generator using only analog mechanics.

I want to run a DC power on a conductor first, then use a Magneto Dynamo (with permanent magnets) to induce an AC on the conductor by rotating the dynamo near it.

Would it be possible to induce an AC power on the DC conductor using magnetic induction?

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to rectify an AC line to a DC line, and yes I'm aware of the dangerous implications of inducing AC on a DC line. That's not my question. I just want to know if it's possible, and what is the science and terminology behind it so I can study it further. That's all.

Comment: No such thing as a DC conductor. No such thing as an AC conductor. No such thing as inducing power. Magnetic induction induces voltage.

Comment: The best places for you to start your independent study would be high school physics text books and other course materials. If nothing else, you'll come away with lots of search terms to continue searching. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If we're just talking about a piece of metal like wire, conductors aren't specific to DC or AC. Nothing is really DC, since for something to be truly DC it would have to have existed since the beginning of time at a constant level and continue to exist to the end of time at that same constant level. The fact it has to start and stop means it has to change means there is technically an AC part to every DC. Just very slow changing even if it only exists at the beginning or end.

> "*I want to run a DC power on a conductor first, then use a Magneto Dynamo (with permanent magnets) to induce an AC on the conductor by rotating the dynamo near it.*"

This will produce an AC signal that is offset (biased) by the DC component. As in, if the AC part is sinusoidal from +1V to -1V normally centered around 0V, and the DC part is +5V, then the entire AC part will be shifted to be centered around the +5V instead so it will be a sinusoid that varies between +6V and +4V.

Comment: Is there a terminology behind this science? So I can look it up and study it further.

Comment: @Darkorse Saturation is a technical term. So is flux. Permeability is the properties of the steel/iron material for how much the flux the core  can support. Your scenario is basically the same as running a transformer with a DC-bias and therefore have to watch for saturation. You're looking at the behaviour of magnetic cores and materials. Things like inductors and transformers. You'll also want to protect your DC supply if you do this your dynamo will basically be trying to backdrive your DC supply which it might not be able to handle.

Comment: @DKNguyen What if I use a superconductor to get zero resistivity, so the power doesn't turn into heat. What would happen then?

Comment: @Darkorse I think you would just get a more perfect short-circuit than with a normal machine and something else outside the magnetic machine would dissipate the power, like the power supply. I think (but am not sure) that the heat generated during saturation is generated in the resistance of the windings rather than the core itself. The nature of super conductors doesn't allow magnetic field lines within the material which means you can't have a superconducting magnetic core material so it doesn't seem to make sense that the core itself can heat up since there's no resistances.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, the superconductor wouldn't allow the magnetic field to stay within the core, but what would happen to the AC power on a DC line within the levitated surface of the superconductor?

Comment: _"However, there is such a thing as saturation which basically means the steel or iron in the dynamo..."_ - this assumes the 'dynamo' has an iron core (the OP appears to be talking about just waving some magnets around the 'DC' conductor). Even if it does, at saturation the flux doesn't drop to zero, just to a lower value equivalent to an ironless generator. _"exceeding the amount of flux that the iron can contain just turns all the power you put into it into heat"_ - no, it doesn't. When the core is saturated it has _less_ loss.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Maybe I worded that wrong. But pumping more energy into a machine with a saturated core just produces incrementally more heat and incrementally less additional electricity,

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, I'm more in line with what you're saying. Thank you for stepping in.

Comment: @DKNguyen your answer would be perfect without the saturation stuff, which is just confusing the issue.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I can remove it if that's what the dynamo is.

Comment: According to Wikipedia a dynamo is "an electrical generator that creates **direct current using a commutator**." - so the OP is actually talking about a magneto or alternator. Magnetos usually have iron somewhere, but how this would be used with a 'DC' line is not explained. So probably best to avoid the topic.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Hm. Yeah didn't notice the way the OP worded that. I can't remember what a magneto is though. OP might be using dynamo just as a machine to move magnets quickly though and placing their own wire near it...which is a bit strange.